# Python encoding issue, Network adapter not recognised

Tags: python, networking, netsh

Here is my piece of python code scratch.

```
 import os
 print 'netsh interface ip set address name="' + adapter + '" static '+ staticaddr +' 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1'
```

Until this point all is fine the adapter is included within my drivers.

Now when i run this (as an administrator)

```
 os.system('netsh interface ipv4 set address name="' + adapter + '" static '+ staticaddr +' 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1')
```

It fires this error:

```
La syntaxe du nom de fichier, de répertoire ou de volume est incorrecte.
```

Which means the command's syntax isn't correct.

I tried `os.system('netsh interface ipv4 set address name="' + adapter.encode('ascii','ignore') + '" static '+ staticaddr +' 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1')`

Now this kind of exception occurs:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Where is the problem exactly ?

My network adapter's name is : `Connexion réseau sans fil`

Answer (score 1):

`adapter.encode('ascii','ignore')` raises `UnicodeDecodeError` because `adapter` is a non-ascii str. To encode it (i.e. convert from unicode to str) Python first tried to decode it (i.e. convert from str to unicode) and failed (`adapter` is non-ascii).

Switch to unicode completely:

```
print (u'netsh interface ip set address name="' + adapter.decode('latin1') + u'" static '+ staticaddr.decode('ascii') + u' 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1').encode('latin1')
```

Comment: Tis unleashes an error of another kind `'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\x82' in position 21: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: I'm using python2 anyways I know it explains,therefor I will try with python3

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar problem in my end.
I have a script that lists all the previously connected wi-fi networks and their passwords. One network specifically ("Gestão TI") was giving me a headache, beacuse when I ran the command, the name came back as "GestÆo TI", and the following command couldn't run, because the name changed.
I tried a few different encodings, such as UTF-8, Latin-1 and others, with no success.
A frind of mine pointed out to me that maybe the problem was with the netsh encoding when it was exporting the names. As the netsh is fairly old, he suggested I tried using the old latin encoding (CP850) and it finally worked...